# Regex pattern to match first 5 digit

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write the regex to match only the first 5 digits instead of the entire 9 Digits of a number.

I have given the Regex below and the regex demo link.

The below regex is what I have

```
(?<![xX])(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d{2,}[._ –-]*\d{2,}[._ –-]*\d{2,}
```

[Regex Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/2)

**Also, if the String "order number" precedes the 9 Digit number, the match should not take place.**

Example Use cases:

Note: If the Number is preceded with 'x' or 'X' it should not get a match.

//should not get match

```
 1. x123456789
 2. X123456789
 3. x123-456-789
 4. X123-456-789
```

//if number is preceded with string "order number / order", then the number should not get matched

```
1. order number 123456789
 2. order.number 123456789
 3. order 123456789
 4. ordernumber 123-456-789
 5. order number 123-456789
 6. order number 123456789
 7. 123-456789
 8. 123456789
 9. ordernumber-x123456787
 10. ordernumber-123456787
 11. ordernumber - 123456789
 12. ordernumber #123456789
 13. ordernumber (anyspl charc)123456789
 14. ordernumber !@#$%^&123456789
 15. 123456789*@*#123456789
 16. social security number 123-456-789
 17. ordernumber !@#$%^&x123456789
 18. 123456789
 19. #@%#$%#$123456789#$%#$^$#
 20. order.number 123456789
 21. order_number123456789
 22. order..number 123456789
 23. order#123456789
```

// The Below use cases are already getting match for 9 digits, but need to get a match for only first 5 digits.

```
 - 123456789
 - 123 45 6789
 - 123-45-6789
 - 123-45-6789
 - 123 – 45 – 6789
 - 123.45.6789
 - 123_45_6789
 - 123 456 789
 - 123-456-789
 - 123 – 456 – 789
 - 123.456.789
 - 123_456_789
 - 1234 56 789
 - 1234-56-789
 - 1234 – 56 – 789
 - 1234.56.789
 - 1234_56_789
 - 12 345 6789
 - 12-345-6789
 - 12 – 345 – 6789
 - 12.345.6789
 - 12_345_6789
```

Any help on this to modify the regex above to match only the first 5 digits?

Comment: Is it being done in Javascript?

Comment: You cannot do it with just a single capturing group, there is no way to tell where the fifth digit will go. This needs access to the code.

Comment: @anubhava, We just have to detect the above numbers and match only the first 5 digits from it. No coding procedure required. Like doing negative look ahead or greedy stuff. something like that

Comment: is it possible to match first 5 digit alone for a straight 9 Digit numbers without any special characters involved in it?

Comment: @anubhava, i Have this regex

`(?:^|(?<=[\D;a-zA-Z(),.:;?!"'`>]))(?!000|666|9)(?<!order.)(?<!order..)(?<!order...)(?<!order.number.)(?<!order.number..)(?<!order.number...)(?<!x)\d{3}[ -.=\n\r]{0,10}(?!00)\d{2}[ -.=\n\r]{0,10}(?!0000)\d{4}(?:$|(?=[\Da-zA-Z(),.:;?!"'`<= ]))`

which will not match of the order number string is preceded. But few use cases are not working...

Comment: You can only get first 5 digits in a capture group that may include special characters as well (based on your input). You can remove special characters later. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want to have the last 4 digits of that 9 Digit Number to not be matched. So it doesn't matter if we match all the numbers and characters except the last 4 digits. Is that possible with regex?

Comment: @anubhava, the other way round is, 

I want to have the last 4 digits of that 9 Digit Number to not be matched. So it doesn't matter if we match all the numbers and characters except the last 4 digits. Is that possible with regex?

Comment: Not sure you can do this without breaking the logic. Try https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, hey yea this is what i want. Just match the First 5 digit of that numbers. Is it possible to ignore the match if the string order number is preceded to that? That is the only thing pending.

Comment: Maybe add the `(?<!\border number )` lookbehind, see https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, [link](regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/5), even after adding the negative lookbehind, use cases are still getting the match for the first 5 digits. Are we adding it in the correct place?

Comment: Depending on how we are treating it afterwards we could get the 5 digits in 5 capturing groups?

Comment: @Kendle, `https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/5` This is the outcome i require. Just match the First 5 digits which is working fine. Now, i want to ignore the match if the string "order number / order" preceding the 9 digit number. You can see the use cases in the regex demo from the link given in this comment.

Comment: If you target .NET or modern JavaScript environments, https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/6 must work for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes this is awesome. Exact solution i was looking for. Thank you so much for making my day!  You can add it as an answer with explanation if you wish to :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Hey Thanks for your help on this. There is something i wanna let you know that when i try to put the regex and save it in the configuration settings, it says the following error 

""regex" expression has potentially catastrophic backtracking"

Comment: Kamesh, I doubt you will ever hit that in reality with this regex. The `(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0` and `(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3}` checks can be resource consuming, but since the limiting quantifiers on the sequences are set to really small values, `3` and `5`, in real life you'd need a very long and convolutely built string to even try to come close to catastrophic backtracking. Also, if it is SonarQube, ignore it, it overfires all the time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it is Genesys Designer which is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/(?<!x)(?<!\border\s*number\W*)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})\d(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF8x6C/6). *Details*:

- `(?<!x)` - a location not immediately preceded with `x` or `X` (the pattern is case insensitive due to `i` flag)
- `(?<!\border\s*number\W*)` - immediately on the left, there cannot be `order` number`whole word with any amount of whitespaces between the two words and any amount of non-word chars between`number` and the next digit
- `(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})` - immediately on the right, there must be nine occurrences of zero or more dashes, underscore, space or hyphens and a digit
- `(?!9|66\D*6|00\D*0|(?:\d\D*){3}0\D*0|(?:\d\D*){5}0(?:\D*0){3})` - immediately on the right, there can be no `9`, or `66` + zero or more non-digits and then `6`, or `00` + zero or more non-digits and then `0`, or three occurrences of a digit and then any zero or more non-digit chars and then `0`, any zero or more non-digit chars and then a `0`, or five occurrences of a digit and then any zero or more non-digit chars and then `0`, and three occurrences of any zero or more non-digit chars and then a `0`
- `\d` - a digit is matched
- `(?:[._ –-]*\d){4}` - and the four sequences of any zero or more spaces, dashes, hyphens or underscores and then a digit.